# Mojave App Store Updates page only shows one item

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, mojave

I'm on 10.14.1 Beta 5 but this has been occurring since the official release of Mojave.

When I open the App Store and click on the Updates tab on the left, I expect to see a list of apps that were recently updated (as well as a list of any apps that have updates pending).

However, all I see is a single app that was recently updated (none of the previous updates). It's also not the most recent app I updated.

[image: app store updates shows one recent update]

If there are pending updates, it will only show an update if Mojave tried to automatically install it in the background, warned me the app can't be updated while it's running, and I hit cancel. And even in this case, it only shows the one update (in place of the one that displayed there before).

I've tried:

- signing out of the app store and signing back in.
- clicking the Store > Refresh Page menu item (cmd-R)

I've hunted around a bit and haven't found any similar reports, any ideas on how to get the app store to show all of my updates past and present?

Comment: ß is no longer supported